# How to fix the height of this grid?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKMRV.png)I created a four column content grid which contains image and text inside of it.The problem i am facing is that the height of grid boxes are not equal.when ever there is short text the boxes spending according to text length. here is my code for better understanding

html:

```
<ul class="rig">
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <h2><strong>This text 1</strong></h2>
        <img src="css/images/image.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <h2><strong>This text 2</strong></h2>
        <img src="css/images/image1.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <h2><strong>This text 3</strong></h2>
        <img src="css/images/image2.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <h2><strong>This text 4</strong></h2>
        <img src="css/images/image3.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>   </ul>
```

css:

```
ul.rig {
list-style: none;
font-size: 0px;
margin-left: -4.3%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
ul.rig li {
width: 170px;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
padding: 2px 3px 5px;
background: #F1f1f1 url() repeat-x top;
border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
font-size: 16px;
font-size: 1rem;
vertical-align: top;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ddd;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
margin-left: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
}
ul.rig li a {
text-decoration: none;
}
ul.rig li img {
width: 145px;
height: 180px;
margin: 5px 7px 14px;
border: 2px solid #535355;
padding: 0px 0px;
transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
ul.rig li img:hover {
opacity: 0.7;
}
ul.rig li h2 {
color: #222;
font-weight: bold;
font: 14px Oswald;
line-height: 12px;
text-shadow: 2px 3px 4px #fff;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 4px;
padding: 2px;
text-align: center;
}
ul.rig li h2:hover {
color: #0470d9;
}
```

[i have added an image of what is happening and what i want to accomplish
please have look at the second image,i think this will make it clear what i want to acomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxdFp.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solution for now:
1) Add read more for long paragaph
2) Set min-height ( height of your bigest paragrpah, so every box will be the same)

Comment: can i use box-sizing to set the height of each boxes same ?

Comment: gogle for flex, also 
http://clearleft.com/thinks/270
this will help you
Or give us full code on jsfidle or codepen.. and we wil help you

Answer (score 0):

A solution will be to use `max-height` in CSS on the `rig` class.

```
.rig li {
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: can you please take a look at the second image i have posted.

Comment: Than use **min-height**.